# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined array shuffle in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, shuffle

I am new to React and I am trying to figure out how I can shuffle an array. I have tried different way to shuffle the array but the problem is always with the length. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. I am not sure why this is happening or how I should deal with it in React. To me, this shouldn't be an issue with React but again I don't know. What should happen when everything works:

You click on the button 'hard' and it should render the two first elements from the array challenge, and every time you click on that button the array should be shuffled.

Do you have any idea that could help me?

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let era = [
  60, 70, 80, 90, 2000
]

let genre = [
  'Rock', 'Pop', 'Jazz', 'Country'
]

let challenge = [
  'LikeElvis', 'Parent\'s favourite songs', 'too high for me'
]

class Karaoke extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      'easy': '',
      'easyChallenge': '',
      'hard': '',
      'hardChallenge': '',
      'hardEra': ''
    }
  };

  selectEasy = () => {
    let genreSelected = [];
    let challengeSelected = [];
    genreSelected.push(genre[Math.floor(Math.random() * genre.length)]);
    this.setState({"easy": genreSelected})

    challengeSelected.push(challenge[Math.floor(Math.random() * challenge.length)]);
    this.setState({"easyChallenge": challengeSelected})
  }

  selectHard = () => {
    let genreSelected = [];
    let challengeSelected = [];
    let eraSelected = [];
    genreSelected.push(genre[Math.floor(Math.random() * genre.length)]);
    eraSelected.push(era[Math.floor(Math.random() * era.length)]);

    this.setState({ "hard": genreSelected} );
    this.setState({ "hardEra": eraSelected} );
    this.setState({ "hardChallenge": challengeSelected} );

    challengeSelected.push(challenge.slice(0, 2))
    console.log(challengeSelected);
  }

  shuffle = (challenge) => {
    let i = challenge.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    while (0 !== i) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      i -= 1;
      temporaryValue = challenge[i];
      challenge[i] = challenge[randomIndex];
      challenge[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return challenge
  }

  click = () => {
    this.selectHard();
    this.shuffle();
  }

  render = () => {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.selectEasy}>Easy</button>
        <button onClick={this.click}>Hard</button>
        <h1>the genre is {this.state.easy} </h1>
        <h1>the challenge is {this.state.easyChallenge} </h1>
        <h1>Hard mode: {this.state.hard} + {this.state.hardEra + '\'s'}</h1>
        <h1>Hard mode challenge: {this.state.hardChallenge} </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }

}


ReactDOM.render(<Karaoke />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: the error message is not indicating that there is a problem with the length, but rather that the object you're trying to get the length from is not an array but is undefined.

Comment: Sometimes you are using arrow functions, sometimes not. Consider unifying your code.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I have seen this and tried it, but I got the same error with the length.

Comment: @Logar Why? They are global variables and component have an access to them. Anyways - `shuffle = (challenge) => {` remove `challenge` from this line and should work properly, probably.

Comment: Removed my comment as indeed it was not your problem at all. But I'm really not sure declaring let variables outside of the class to use them inside is a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your `suffle` method expecting an argument. But then when you call it from the `click` method you are not providing said argument:

```
shuffle(challenge) {
    // ...
}

click = () => {
    // ...
    this.shuffle();
}
```

This will cause the declared argument to be `undefined` and the `suffle` method will not default the global `challenge` variable.

To solve this, you need to either remove the argument from the method defintion or pass it in the `click` function:

```
shuffle() {
    // ...
}
click = () => {
    // ...
    this.shuffle();
}

/* OR */

shuffle(challenge) {
    // ...
}
click = () => {
    // ...
    this.shuffle(challenge);
}
```